# Proving Bezout's Theorem

Tags: number-theory, euclidean-algorithm

I need to prove Bezout's Theorem and the recommended method is using the induction on the number of steps before the Euclidean algorithm terminates for a given input pair.$~~~~~~$

I am having hard time understanding what it means of the number of steps before the Euclidean algorithm terminates for a given input pair. Please help me!

Comment: The Euclidian algorithm consists in successive divisions. From an initial pair $(a,b)$ we deduce another one $(b,r)$ by an euclidian quotient : $a = b \times q + r$. Then we repeat until $r$ equals $0$. The *number of steps* is simply the number of divisons, is this what you need ?

Comment: I understand the EA but don't know how to incorporate induction on the number of steps that EA terminates even for the base case. If I know how to come up with the base case, I would feel confident on doing k+1.

Comment: @BusyAnt thanks for pointing out the number of divisions! I was confused on the terminology of "the number of steps'

Answer (score 1):

You can use another induction, which is useful to understand  the *Extended Euclidean algorithm*: it consists in proving that all successive remainders in the algorithm satisfy a Bézout's identity whatever the number of steps, by a finite induction or order $2$.

Initialisation is easy, as the first two remainders are $r_0=a$ and $r_1=b$, you have:
$$a=1\cdot a+0\cdot b,\quad=0\cdot a+1\cdot b.$$

At the $i$-step, you have $r_{i-1}=q_ir_i+r_{i+1}$. By induction hypothesis, we have:
$$r_{i-1}=u_{i-1}a+v_{i-1}b,\quad r_i=u_ia+v_ib $$
whence
$$r_{i+-1}=r_{i-1}-q_ir_i=(u_{i-1}-q_iu_i)a+(v_{i-1}-q_iv_i)b.$$

Icing on the cake: you get the recurrence relations between the coefficients, ready for use in the Extended Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: @Wren This proof also shows you how to find the *Bezout integers* $u$ and $v$ : all you have to do is to read the EA backwards ! It requires a little practice but always work

Comment: It is better to use the EEA, computing progressively *all* Bézout's coefficients. Btw, it is Bézout, not Bezout.